# Unable to read csv file present in S3 from Sagemaker R studio

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am trying to read a csv file which is present in AWS s3 from Sagemaker R studio. I tried the below code.

```
library(reticulate)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
boto3 <- import("boto3")
s3 <- boto3$client('s3')
d <- s3$download_file(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=path, Filename="file_name.csv")
```

i receive ClientError: An error occured (404) when calling the head object operation. Could some one please help

Comment: [How to use Boto3 to download an object from S3 using AWS Resource?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-boto3-to-download-an-object-from-s3-using-aws-resource) check this out

Comment: i am using R to download and read the csv file

Comment: 404 means not found, of course. Is there actually an object at that bucket/key? Does the key have any special characters?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, there was a typo in file name, now it is not giving any error but if i print d it returns NULL but i do have data in the file. Any idea why it is returning NULL not the data.

Comment: Attempted to address the NULL return value in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 404 means Not Found. This happens when the object with the indicated key does not actually exist in the indicated S3 bucket. Check that you are using the correct bucket name and key name.

Note that the boto3 [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) function does not return a value (which I presume maps to NULL in R). The function saves the downloaded file to the filename you passed in when making the call, `file_name.csv` in your example. So, you will need to open and read the downloaded CSV file.